# unable to check nodes on hadoop [Connection refused]

Tags: hadoop

If I type  `http://localhost:50070` or  `http://localhost:9000` to see the nodes,my browser shows me nothing I think it can't connect to the server.
I tested my hadoop with this command:

```
hadoop jar hadoop-*test*.jar TestDFSIO -write -nrFiles 10 -fileSize 1000
```

but too didn't work and it tries to connect to the server,this is the output:

```
12/06/06 17:25:24 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: nrFiles = 10
12/06/06 17:25:24 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: fileSize (MB) = 1000
12/06/06 17:25:24 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: bufferSize = 1000000
12/06/06 17:25:25 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 0 time(s).
12/06/06 17:25:26 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 1 time(s).
12/06/06 17:25:27 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 2 time(s).
12/06/06 17:25:28 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 3 time(s).
12/06/06 17:25:29 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 4 time(s).
12/06/06 17:25:30 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 5 time(s).
12/06/06 17:25:31 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 6 time(s).
12/06/06 17:25:32 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 7 time(s).
12/06/06 17:25:33 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 8 time(s).
12/06/06 17:25:34 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 9 time(s).
java.net.ConnectException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

I changed some files like this:
in conf/core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
```

in conf/hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
</configuration>
```

in conf/mapred-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:9001</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Thanks for your attention. If I run this command:

```
cat /etc/hosts
```

I see:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ubuntu.ubuntu-domain    ubuntu

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

and if i run this one:

```
ps axww | grep hadoop
```

I see this result:

```
2170 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto hadoop
```

but no effect. Have you any idea, how can I solve my problem?

Comment: What's in your /etc/hosts file?

Comment: I did'nt find that,do you know,where is exactly host file?

Comment: Check the hadoop namenode and datanode logs in $HADOOP_HOME/logs, and see if you find any error or exception. It is better to check right after starting hadoop

Comment: @Raze2dust :I'm new in this field.I could not find any logs file or folder in my HADOOP_HOME path.Can I run it from terminal?

Comment: If you're on your shell then use `cat /etc/hosts` and post the output here in your question.

Comment: Can you also post the output of running the command `ps axww | grep hadoop` in an terminal (post it into your question, not as a comment please)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are few things that you need to take care of before starting hadoop services.

Check what this returns:

```
hostname --fqdn
```

In your case this should be localhost. 
Also comment out IPV6 in /etc/hosts.

Did you format the namenode before starting HDFS.

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

How did you install Hadoop. Location of log files will depend on that. Usually it is in location "/var/log/hadoop/" if you have used cloudera's distribution.

If you are a complete newbie, I suggest installing Hadoop using Cloudera SCM which is quite easy. I have posted [my approach in installing Hadoop](http://pyfunc.blogspot.com/2012/05/hadoop-pseudo-cluster-installation.html) with Cloudera's distribution.

## Also

Make sure DFS location has a **write permission**. It usually sits @ `/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs`

That is a common reason.

Comment: I had the same problem. After the name node formatting it fixed the problem. But, I had to create the home directory using "hdfs dfs -mkdir /user; hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/{my-user-name}

Comment: @pyfunc, Do you say the output of my `hostname --fqdn` should be `localhost`?  my is hadoopmaster.

Answer (score 4):

same problem i got and this solved my problem:

problem lies with the permission given to the folders
"chmod" 755 or greater for the folders
/home/username/hadoop/*

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is the namenode is not running.

You can remove the HDFS files:

```
rm -rf /tmp/hadoop*
```

Reformat the HDFS

```
bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

And restart hadoop services

```
bin/hadoop/start-all.sh (Hadoop 1.x)
```

or

```
sbin/hadoop/start-all.sh (Hadoop 2.x)
```

Answer (score 2):

also edit your /etc/hosts file and change 127.0.1.1 to 127.0.0.1...proper dns resolution is very important for hadoop and a bit tricky too..also add following property in your core-site.xml file -

```
<property>
      <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
      <value>/path_to_temp_directory</value>
    </property>
```

the default location for this property is /tmp directory which get emptied after each system restart..so you loose all your info at each restart..also add these properties in your hdfs-site.xml file -

```
<property>
        <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
        <value>/path_to_name_directory</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
        <value>/path_to_data_directory</value>
    </property>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that is your first installation of hadoop.

At the beginning please check if your daemons are working. To do that use (in terminal):

```
jps
```

If only jps appears that means all daemons are down. Please check the log files. Especially the namenode. Log folder is probably somewhere there /usr/lib/hadoop/logs

If you have some permission problems. Use this guide during the installation.

[Good installation guide](http://blog.timmattison.com/archives/2011/12/23/how-to-install-hadoop-on-debian-ubuntu/)

I am shooting with this explanations but these are most common problems.

Comment: be aware that jps will only display JVMs running for the current user (so if you're running hadoop as a dedicated user, and call jps from another user's session, the hadoop processes won't show up) - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jps.html

Comment: You are right, if you are launching the hadoop in pseudo distributed mode you should use sudo jps because all daemons are run by super user in default. Am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Edit your core conf/core-site.xml and change localhost to 0.0.0.0. Use the conf below. That should work.

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://0.0.0.0:9000</value>
  </property>
```